# Determine Ker(L ◦ L) and Im(L o L)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Give the canonical base $C$  and the base $B = \{ (2,1, 1) , (0, 0, 1) , (1, 1, 3)\}$
Consider the linear application $L : \mathbb{R}^3 \to\mathbb{R}^3$
$$
M_B^C(L) =  
\left[
\begin{matrix}
  3 & 1  & 0 \\
  1 & 2  &-1 \\
  1 & -3 &-2\\
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
Determine $Ker(L \circ L)$ and $Im(L \circ L)$.

I don't quite know how to find it i tried to search on the web but nothing similar came up.

Comment: You should probably start with computing a matrix representative of $L\circ L$.

Comment: Can u guide me how please? just the steps  ^^

Answer (score 0):

Let $F_L:\Bbb R^3 \rightarrow \Bbb R^3 \quad F_L(x)=Lx$. $F_L$ represents the linear application of $L$.
Now we can see that $$(F_L \circ F_L)(x)=F_L(F_L(x))=F_L(Lx)=L^2x$$ so $F_L \circ F_L$ is just $F_{L^2}$. Are you able to go on from that?